# Value of component in IONIC 5

Tags: ionic5, appery.io

What is the equivalent code for this in IONIC 5?

JQM Code:
var EmployeeID = Apperyio('EMP_IDNo').val();

IONIC 5 Code: ???
let EmployID =

I haven't seen documentation regarding getting the  using typescript in Ionic.

Comment: Assuming this is to get the value of `EMP_IDNo` field, in Ionic5 project in Appery, we can define a variable like `EmployeeID` on the page and set `[ngModel]` attribute to `EmployeeID`. 
We can then refer to this variable as `this.EmployeeID` in typescript blocks on this page.

Answer (score 3):

To read values of input components in Appery.io apps, based on Ionic 5 you just need to read variables, which are used in the property [(ngModel)] of that input components:

1. Define the variable
   [image]
2. Select the input component and set the variable to its [(ngModel)] property

[image]

3. Use the TypeScript to read this variable (value of the input component)

[image]